# Passing value to ViewModel from ViewController w/ RxSwift

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I have a scene in an app I have been asked to make changes in.

I am not really familiar with `RxSwift` so please forgive me if this is obvious.

My view controller renders a `WKWebView` which contains a login form. When the user completes the form, a property is sent back which I am currently printing out in the `WKNavigationDelegate`.

What I would like to do is pass that property to my `oauthService` which exists as a dependancy within my `ViewModel`.

I could create a method in the model like

```
  func passPropToServie(_ prop: String) {
        // do something
    }
```

and just call this from the view controller, but I am not sure if this is correct, or what the 'rxswift' way of doing this is.

Sorry again, this is an app I am picking up so the original code is something I still coming to terms with.

**LoginCoordinator**

```
import UIKit
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

class LoginCoordinator: BaseCoordinator<()> {
    typealias Dependencies = HasOAuthService

    private let window: UIWindow
    private let dependencies: Dependencies

    init(window: UIWindow, dependencies: Dependencies) {
        self.window = window
        self.dependencies = dependencies
    }

    override func start() -> Observable<()> {
        let viewController = LoginViewController()
        let avm: Attachable<LoginViewModel> = .detached(dependencies)
        let viewModel = viewController.attach(wrapper: avm)

        viewModel.loginURL.drive(onNext: { login in
            viewController.handle(login?.url)
        }).disposed(by: viewController.disposeBag)

        window.rootViewController = viewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return viewModel.isLoggedIn
            .asObservable()
            .filter { $0 }
            .map { _ in return }
    }
}
```

**LoginViewController**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, ViewModelAttaching {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    var viewModel: Attachable<LoginViewModel>!
    var bindings: LoginViewModel.Bindings {
        return LoginViewModel.Bindings()
    }

    private var requestURL: URL?

    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes = [.all]
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false
        return webView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func loadView() {
        view = webView
    }

    func bind(viewModel: LoginViewModel) -> LoginViewModel {

        return viewModel
    }

    func handle(_ url: URL?) {
        guard let url = url else { return }
        requestURL = url
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}

extension LoginViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url, url.scheme == "homedev", url.valueOf("code") != nil {
            print(url)
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

**LoginViewModel**

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

final class LoginViewModel: ViewModelType {

    typealias Dependency = HasOAuthService

    let isLoggedIn: Driver<Bool>
    let loginURL: Driver<URLComponents?>

    struct Bindings { }

    init(dependency: Dependency, bindings: Bindings) {

        isLoggedIn = dependency.oauthService.currentUser
            .map { user in return user == true }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false)

        loginURL = dependency.oauthService.loginURL
            .map { $0 }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you got the reference to the model then it's totally fine to just call the method on it. If you'd like to update your UI based on the result of the `oauth`, then you could make use of RxSwift/RxCocoa/RxRelay. For the `oauth` itself RxSwift is not of much use IMO. PromiseKit might make things easier though.
Personally I would make the `oauth` request capsulated with a Promise and based on the result alter RxSwift variables where my UI is bound to/listens to.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate you taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how far down the rabbit hole you want to go. Rx is meant to replace all the different ways that we normally push data into objects. So if you take it to the extreme, you won't have any callback closures, @IBActions, or delegates; and you won't assign to a `var`, or call a function with data, just so you can use the data in another class. There are wrappers that will allow you to eliminate the delegate function in your LoginViewController for example.

I'm guessing that the `Bindings` struct is for inputs into the view model, if that's the case, then I would likely add an Observable in the bindings and a publish subject in the view controller. Calling `onNext` on the publish subject would get picked up in the view model through the binding.

You might benefit from reading this article: [Integrating RxSwift Into Your Brain and Code Base](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/integrating-rxswift-into-your-brain-and-code-base-1a790c36c36d)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are correct about `Bindings`, I really do appreciate your feedback. Very helpful.

Comment: Your question feels a bit big for stack overflow. You might benefit from joining our slack community: http://slack.rxswift.org

Comment: Hi @Daniel T. , I hv to learn RxSwift basics & Data transfer within multiple view controllers. Do u having any tutorials ? Can u pls guide me on this?

Comment: My RxEarthquake sample (https://github.com/danielt1263/RxEarthquake) shares an Earthquake model between two view controllers. I also just finished an article (https://medium.com/@danielt1263/viper-rxswift-ified-1ec3ae8ab9a6) that adds a Todo in one view controller an then displays it in another.